# Limit maximum df of smooth in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, gam, mgcv

Firstly, I am very new to R, very basic statistical knowledge and have thus been winging it when it comes to my analysis. This means googling the coding I need for the results, and due to how small some samples are I will have to check if they are of any statistical relevance later. For now, though, I'm just trying to reach my goal of displaying graphs on the screen.

I have two datasets I want to run gams for - one with 9 obs. of 22 variables, the other with 4 obs. of 22 variables (both filtered from a source table of 44 obs. of 22 variables). Example:

```
Flight_Dur    Distance
 429            2396
 59.2           1096
 26.6           1174
```

I'm plotting the linear GAMM with mgcv with this code:

```
GAMM_Plot <- gam(Flight_Dur ~ s(Distance, k = 4), data = my_table, method = "REML")
```

Since I was getting the error message "A term has fewer unique covariate combinations than specified maximum degrees of freedom", I followed [this](https://www.seascapemodels.org/rstats/2021/03/27/common-GAM-problems.html) guide and added k = [number of objects I have], so 4 for one dataset and 9 for the other, to limit my df. Agsin, I don't know what it does to the relevance of my results, I'm just trying to make the graphs work for now.

To visualise scatterplots along with the lines, however, I used:

```
GAMM_Plot2 <- ggplot(my_table, aes(x=Distance, y=Flight_Dur)) + 
  geom_point()+
  geom_smooth(method=gam)
```

Interestingly, plotting the latter won't give me an error message, however both graphs are clearly different since the second one has no limitation set for df. I would like to set this limitation for the ggplot code as well - how would this be possible?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the method to use `mgcv::gam` and the formula including `k = 4`.

```r
my_table <- data.frame(
  Flight_Dur = c(429, 59.2, 26.6, 30),
  Distance = c(2396, 1096, 1174, 1000)
)

library(ggplot2)
library(mgcv)
#> Loading required package: nlme
#> This is mgcv 1.8-33. For overview type 'help("mgcv-package")'.

ggplot(my_table, aes(x=Distance, y=Flight_Dur)) + 
  geom_point()+
  geom_smooth(method = mgcv::gam, formula = y ~ s(x, k = 4))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-09-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

However, I would be a bit careful to use a gam with so few observations.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply specify the formula in terms of `y` and `x` with the default `method = "gam"`

```r
my_table <- data.frame(
  Flight_Dur = c(429, 59.2, 26.6, 30),
  Distance = c(2396, 1096, 1174, 1000)
)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(my_table, aes(x=Distance, y=Flight_Dur)) + 
  geom_point()+
  geom_smooth(method = "gam", formula = y ~ s(x, k = 4))
```

If you are going to do as @starja suggests and pass a function to `method`, you should also set the `method.args` argument to also pass through `method = "REML"` to `mgcv::gam()` so as to match your actual `gam()` call:

```r
ggplot(my_table, aes(x=Distance, y=Flight_Dur)) + 
  geom_point()+
  geom_smooth(method = mgcv::gam, formula = y ~ s(x, k = 4),
              method.args = list(method = "REML"))
```

I don't expect much difference without setting `method.args` for smooths with `k = 4`, but in general GCV and REML smoothness selection can give noticeably different fits.